# Does Magento EE 1.11.2.0 supports Coupon code Auto generation?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1, coupon-codes

Magento EE 1.11.2.0 doesn't have that check box for auto generating the coupon codes. See the below image.

[image]

I doubt whether this functionality has been introduced with later versions from Magento EE 1.14.x

Please any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the source I think it should have this functionality.

The form in question is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main::_prepareForm`

It has a section of code which adds the `coupon_type` form element like

```
    $couponTypeFiled = $fieldset->addField('coupon_type', 'select', array(
        'name'       => 'coupon_type',
        'label'      => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Coupon'),
        'required'   => true,
        'options'    => Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCouponTypes(),
    ));
```

`Mage_Salesrule_Model_Rule::getCouponTypes()` is defined like

```
/**
 * Retrieve coupon types
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCouponTypes()
{
    if ($this->_couponTypes === null) {
        $this->_couponTypes = array(
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No Coupon'),
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC  => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Specific Coupon'),
        );
        $transport = new Varien_Object(array(
                'coupon_types' => $this->_couponTypes,
                'is_coupon_type_auto_visible' => false
        ));
        Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_rule_get_coupon_types', array('transport' => $transport));
        $this->_couponTypes = $transport->getCouponTypes();
        if ($transport->getIsCouponTypeAutoVisible()) {
            $this->_couponTypes[Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Auto');
        }
    }
    return $this->_couponTypes;
}
```

You can see that the auto coupon type is toggled and controlled by an observer `salesrule_rule_get_coupon_types`.

The only vanilla observer for this that I can see is the `Enterprise_Reminder_Model_Observer::getCouponTypes` method which is defined like

```
public function getCouponTypes($observer)
{
    if ($transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport()) {
        $transport->setIsCouponTypeAutoVisible(true);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If you're not seeing this auto option appearing, I would make sure the Enterprise_Reminder module is enabled in `app/etc/modules/Enterprise_Reminder.xml`

If it still isn't appearing, make sure no other observer is defined with an xml path like

```
    <events>
        <salesrule_rule_get_coupon_types>
            <observers>
                <enterprise_reminder>
```